# How use UEFI locate_protocol in a rust project with r_efi crate

Tags: rust, ffi, uefi

In a cross-compiled educative project with rust and the [crate r_efi](https://docs.rs/r-efi/3.2.0/r_efi/index.html) and without the rust standard library, I wanna make a small program to UEFI systems. For the moment, the goal is to be able to use the graphical output protocol.

Through the use of r_efi crate, I start by locating the **GOP** with the system module :

**r_efi::system::BootServices::locate_protocol**

The definition is :

```
locate_protocol: extern "win64" fn(_: *mut Guid, _: *mut c_void, _: *mut *mut c_void) -> Status
```

My problem is this 2 parameters :

```
_: *mut c_void
```

and

```
_: *mut *mut c_void
```

I don't know how return **core::ffi::c_void** parameters like in a C code :

```
EFI_STATUS efi_main(EFI_HANDLE image, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *systemTable) {
      EFI_BOOT_SERVICES *bs = systemTable->BootServices;
      EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL *graphicsProtocol;
      EFI_STATUS status;

      status = bs->LocateProtocol(&GraphicsOutputProtocolGUID, NULL, (void**)&graphicsProtocol);
```

Thank in advance for your explanations.

Comment: References can be coerced into pointers, and pointers are always inter-coercible. One can get a void pointer using something like `&mut x as *mut T as *mut core::ffi::c_void`.

Comment: @RuifengXie : Hmm ok, this can work?
`&mut ptr::null() as *mut c_void` ?
however, for the second parameter, I don't really understand what to return.

Comment: I don’t understand. In the C code presented, you pass the address of a pointer to a `EFI_GRAPHICS_PROTOCOL` (coerced into `void**`). But now you suddenly want to pass a pointer to null pointer instead... I suppose in Rust you would also want something like `let mut graphics_protocol: *<the corresponding Rust type> = ptr::null_mut(); &mut graphics_protocol as *mut *_ as *mut *c_void`.

Comment: Ok understand. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here a code solution ( working on virtualbox ) to locate the graphical output protocol with the r_efi crate :

```
#[export_name = "efi_main"]
pub extern fn main(_h: efi::Handle, st: *mut efi::SystemTable) -> efi::Status {

     let mut gop: *mut efi::protocols::graphics_output::Protocol = ptr::null_mut();
     let mut guid_gop: efi::Guid = efi::protocols::graphics_output::PROTOCOL_GUID;

     let stats = unsafe { ((*(*st).boot_services).locate_protocol)(
            &mut guid_gop as *mut _,
            ptr::null_mut(),
            &mut gop as *mut _ as *mut *mut core::ffi::c_void,
     )};

     match stats {

        efi::Status::SUCCESS => {...},
        efi::Status::NOT_FOUND => {...},

     }

     efi::Status::SUCCESS
}
```